# Cocos2d custom font file - issue with character id

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing cocos2d game, which supports multiple languages. I created a font file(.png and .fnt) with all  supported characters.

The issue is some of the character id's are in range of 917505-917631. So I set kCCBMFontMaxChars = 917632. But this is taking lot of memory.

Can anyone please tell me how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kCCBMFontMaxChars = 0xffff;  // 65k
```

This should suffice for all Unicode characters. It certainly works for all the asian and cyrillic languages. The memory usage will be exactly 2 MB.

Don't worry about the ID, I believe they are offsets into the BMFont char array and not indexes. Each entry is 32 Bytes. 917632 divided by 32 gives you 28676, which if it is an index fits within the unicode character range.